# How to stop my character from going outside the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm just starting to see Jquery and I've been struggling with finding a way to make my character stop once it touches the end of the div or the walls of the div.

this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

var position = $('#charlie').position();

switch(e.keyCode) {

    case 39: // right
    $('#charlie').css('left', position.left + 20 + 'px').removeClass('flip');
    break;

    case 37: // left
    $('#charlie').css('left', position.left - 20 + 'px').addClass('flip');

}


});
```

css:

```
body {

padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
font-family: jennaSue;
font-size: 50px;
}

.container {
background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);
display: block; 
margin: auto;
max-width: 500px;
height: 340px;
padding: 10px;
}

#charlie {
    width: 70px; 
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 260px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

.flip {
    transform:scaleX(-1);
}
```

and HTML code:

```
</head>
<body>

<h1>Charlie Brown Run and Dodge</h1>


<div class="container">
    <img src="img/charlie-brown.png" id="charlie" class="character">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify, my character (#charlie) right now moves outside the div. I want it to stay within the div, to stop moving at the (right/left) edge.

Comment: The general idea is to get the width of your `#charlie` object, and then compare it's position + width to determine if it's outside the bounds of the div.

Comment: You should *really* be using a canvas for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is check the bounds in your keydown handler:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {

var position = $('#charlie').position(),
    width = $('#charlie').width(),
    max = $('.container').width(),
    step = 20;

switch(e.keyCode) {

    case 39: // right
    if ( position.left + width + step < max ) {
        $('#charlie').css('left', position.left + step + 'px').removeClass('flip');
    }
    break;

    case 37: // left
    if ( position.left - step > 0 ) {
        $('#charlie').css('left', position.left - step + 'px').addClass('flip');
    }

}


});
```

Also, I changed the several occurrences of `20` to a `step` variable so if you want to tune it, you only have to change it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var maxLeft = $('.container').width;
...
case 39: // right
var newLeft = position.left + 20;
newLeft = min(newLeft, maxLeft);
$('#charlie').css('left', newLeft + 'px').removeClass('flip');
break;
...
```

In this way you calculate the maximum left value for your container and after keypress you compare the new and the max value and get the min value from both and set this as new left value for your image.